# How to create Alert using HTML5-based Iphone application

Tags: iphone, html, alarm

I am creating HTML5 application for iphone, does it possible to create alerts in some predefined time point even the application is not running ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a web app cannot trigger background notifications.

Comment: Correct, that won't make a difference. There simply is not an API in Safari that can hook into the device's notifications.

Comment: dose this have a sense ? http://onepixelahead.com/2010/05/31/html5-notification-example/

Comment: Can I combine the app between a WebView that shows the HTMLs and the objective-c code for dreating a background notifications ?!

Comment: Yes, PhoneGap would be a good example of that sort of hybrid app. Safari doesn't support HTML5 notifications like that link yet (and even if it did, it wouldn't work in the background).

Comment: ok thanks, does JQueryMobile a good option for creating a hybrid app ?

Comment: You could use jQuery Mobile in a PhoneGap app, but it isn't a hybrid app platform by itself.